# Scrapy response.status not 100% accurate?

Tags: scrapy, httpresponse

I'm using `l.add_value('http_status', response.status)` to capture the response status of each domain and store it in a SQL database but some domains do not have a response status (null). At first, I thought that they might be blocking scrapy but when I run scrapy again on those domains I get back a status of 200. Before I implement a second check using urllib, I thought I'd ask here to see if anyone has experienced this before or has any advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there are a few reasons for why the request didn't receive a response,

1)DNS didn't find it in time i.e wasn't resolved (increase `DNS_TIMEOUT`)

2)server took a while to respond (increase `DOWNLOAD_TIMEOUT`)

3)if you are checking for large files >1Gb (increase `DOWNLOAD_MAXSIZE`)

4)Internet connection problem on your side (DNS resolved but you lost connection after)

5)the web server is temporarily down